# Trying to Copy Workbook data but when Source opens nothing happens

Tags: excel, vba

```
I'm using the following code:

Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim targetBook As Workbook

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set targetBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set sourceBook = Application.Workbooks.Open("...\Documents\Log.xlsm")

'
With sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    targetBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

'Close
sourceBook.Close
```

But when i run it my source book opens and nothing happens after. Not sure what i'm missing. Both workbooks have the same extension xlsm. Ive tried to change the source to xlsx also but Same result

Edit: Ive replaced the with statement with the following:
targetBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

to at least see if i can copy 1 value but when the sourcebook is opened it stops there.

Comment: Maybe add a `Debug.Print .Address` inside the `With` block and see what the used range actually is?

Comment: Something is happening before the with statement. Ive replaced the with statement with the following:
targetBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = sourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

to at least see if i can copy 1 value but when the sourcebook is opened it stops there.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your example, and think it is do with the way you are opening the document. In your open method you have three dots Open("...\documents")

It raised an error for me, so can you check that is what you meant? It worked if I used ..\ rather than ...\

Comment: Yes, you can call `.Value` = `.Value` on a range... it is called value transfer and it avoids the clipboard.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, I have updated the answer to what I think may be the issue. Ricardo_r21 is that the issue?

Comment: Not, as OP has it is correct, you don't want to use `Selection` here.

Comment: @Simon no sir it didn't.

Comment: I have updated the example (in case you didn't get an alert)

Comment: @Simon I edited to show 3 dots to not show my entire address since it was on a work computer therefore with personal address. I couldn't get it to work for me instead i'm just having the user copy paste data manually.

Comment: Maybe the work computers have additional policies. I used your code and got it to work :( I assume the LOG excel is a macro enabled one? Obviously *this* workbook must be, to have the macro running, but is the source one or is that an error? (having got it to work my end, it is very much straw clutching now)